# Why does setuptools create egg-info for both my project and for "UNKNOWN"

Tags: python, setuptools, egg, pipenv-install

I'm using the flat source model of project organization, in that `pyproject.toml` and `setup.py` live at the same level as `sampleproj` source directory.

```
sampleproj/
    LICENSE.md
    pyproject.toml
    README.md
    sampleproj/
        main.py
        __init__.py
    setup.py
```

When I use pipenv to install my project in my virtualenv (`pipenv install -e .`), it (presumably through `setuptools`) creates a `sampleproj.egg-info` along with `UNKNOWN.egg-info`.  The `UNKNOWN.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` is basically the README, LICENSE, setup.py, and pyproj.toml. While the SOURCES.txt for the `sampleproj.egg-info` includes with .py files as well as the others.

What is the purposes of the non-.py version of egg-info? Why is it called UNKNOWN? And is there some purpose of it that I'm not aware of?

I'm guessing that it shouldn't be created, but I'm not sure *how* it is being created, so I'm unclear on how to *fix* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the tool chain. Waiting 6 months and upgrading solved the problem.